# django IntegerField использовать в качестве integer

Tags: python, django

Для автоматического заполнения даты следующего подтверждения через заданное количество месяцев (тоже задается в форме) в models.py использую следующий код:

```py
class Next_period(models.Model):
    last_approv = models.DateField()
    period = models.IntegerField()
    next_approv = models.DateField(default=last_approv + relativedelta(months=period))
```

Выдает ошибку

```sh
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'IntegerField'
```

Как получить из заполненного поля integerField значение integer или string?
Или как автоматически к указанной дате прибавлять указанное количество месяцев?

Comment: Во-первых, "из заполненного поля" - вы вычисляете выражение в момент создания класса, и там не существует никаких заполненных полей

Comment: Во-вторых, то, что вы хотите, сделать всё равно невозможно. Задавайте значение или во вьюхе, или в методе save, или ещё что-нибудь типа того

Comment: спасибо! Буду копать в этом направлении